# MongoDB ExpressJS can't return variable with array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, callback

I need to get a variable **x** with array of db data but I can't make it.
When I console.log(**x**) in **findReviews** function all okay but when I return x variable from **findReviews** and console.log(**x**) outside function I'm gets an error : **ReferenceError: x is not defined**. How I can "export" this variable outside and use in another places?

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/instagramdb';

//Get From DB Reviews
function findReviews(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  var collection = db.collection('randComments');

  // Find some documents
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    callback(docs);
  });
}



// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
     findReviews(db, function (docs) {
        var x = docs
        return x
      });
      console.log(x);
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: findReviews is async method. It will return docs data only in callback function. So in order to log X..put console.log(x) and db.close inside findReviews callback function just before return x; Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay... But I need to get array of data and handle this guy in my html render function.

Comment: then again inside findReviews method..you just use res.send(docs); if you use express...